# Table View Cells Not Selectable After Resigning UITextView as First Responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITextView in a UITableViewCell. I have set it to become first responder when the cell is selected as so:

```
TPNTableViewCell *thisCell = (TPNTableViewCell *)[tblMain cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];

thisCell.txtHidden.text=@"";
[thisCell.txtHidden becomeFirstResponder];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(goAwayKeyboard)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

So when the cell is selected txtHidden becomes first responder. And then the selector goAwayKeyboard is triggered when you click out of the keyboard.

```
-(void)goAwayKeyboard
{
    TPNTableViewCell *thisCell = (TPNTableViewCell *)[tblMain cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    [thisCell.txtHidden resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This works, however after the keyboard is resigned I can no longer select a cell in the table view. I can scroll the table view, but the cells aren't selectable and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tap gesture recognizer is probably swallowing all touch events after it's added to the view. Perhaps removing it in `-goAwayKeyboard` would restore touch interaction.

Comment: So I tried adding a property to the view controller @property UIGestureRecognizer *tap, and then in goAwayKeyboard I did [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:tap]; . But that didn't work either. I also tried setting the table view as the first responder and that didn't work. It's weird that the table view still drags it just doesn't respond to clicks.

Comment: Nevermind. I was accidentally calling the function twice that added the gesture recognizer. Silly me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the tap gesture in go away keyboard, You can do this with the help of below code,

```
tap.enabled = NO;
```